# Accuracy not growing across epochs on keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network, text-classification

I'm new to machine learning and deep learning and I'm trying to classify texts from 5 categories using neural networks. For that, I made a dictionary in order to translate the words to indexes, finally getting an array with lists of indexes. Moreover I change the labels to integers. I also did the padding and that stuff. The problem is that when I fit the model the accuracy keeps quite low (~0.20) and does not change across the epochs. I have tried to change a lot of params, like the size of the vocabulary, number of neurones, dropout probability, optimizer parameter, etc. The key parts of the code are below.

```
# Arrays with indexes (that works fine)
X_train = tokens_to_indexes(tokenized_tr_mrp, vocab, return_vocab=False)
X_test, vocab_dict = tokens_to_indexes(tokenized_te_mrp, vocab)

# Labels to integers
labels_dict = {}
labels_dict['Alzheimer'] = 0
labels_dict['Bladder Cancer'] = 1
labels_dict['Breast Cancer'] = 2
labels_dict['Cervical Cancer'] = 3
labels_dict['Negative'] = 4

y_train = np.array([labels_dict[i] for i in y_tr])
y_test = np.array([labels_dict[i] for i in y_te])

# One-hot encoding of labels
from keras.utils import to_categorical
encoded_train = to_categorical(y_train)
encoded_test = to_categorical(y_test)

# Padding
max_review_length = 235
X_train_pad = sequence.pad_sequences(X_train, maxlen=max_review_length)
X_test_pad = sequence.pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=max_review_length)

# Model
# Vocab size
top_words = len(list(vocab_dict.keys()))
# Neurone type
rnn = LSTM
# dropout
set_dropout = True
p = 0.2
# embedding size
embedding_vector_length = 64
# regularization strength
L = 0.0005
# Number of neurones
N = 50

# Model
model = Sequential()
# Embedding layer
model.add(Embedding(top_words,
                   embedding_vector_length,
                   embeddings_regularizer=regularizers.l1(l=L),
                   input_length=max_review_length
                    #,embeddings_constraint=UnitNorm(axis=1)
                   ))

# Dropout layer
if set_dropout:
    model.add(Dropout(p))

# Recurrent layer
model.add(rnn(N))

# Output layer
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))

# Compilation
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
             optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001),
             metrics=['Accuracy'])

# Split training set for validation
X_tr, X_va, y_tr_, y_va = train_test_split(X_train_pad, encoded_train, 
                                          test_size=0.3, random_state=2)

# Parameters
batch_size = 50
# N epochs
n_epocas = 20

best_val_acc  = 0
best_val_loss = 1e20
best_i        = 0

best_weights = []
acum_tr_acc = []
acum_tr_loss = []
acum_val_acc = []
acum_val_loss = []

# Training
for e in range(n_epocas):
    h = model.fit(X_tr, y_tr_,
                batch_size=batch_size,
                validation_data=(X_va, y_va),
                epochs=1, verbose=1)
  
    acum_tr_acc  = acum_tr_acc  + h.history['accuracy']
    acum_tr_loss = acum_tr_loss + h.history['loss']
    val_acc  = h.history['val_accuracy'][0]
    val_loss = h.history['val_loss'][0]
    acum_val_acc  = acum_val_acc  + [val_acc]
    acum_val_loss = acum_val_loss + [val_loss]
#   if val_acc  > best_val_acc:
    if val_loss < best_val_loss:
        best_i        = len(acum_val_acc)-1
        best_val_acc  = val_acc
        best_val_loss = val_loss
        best_weights = model.get_weights().copy()
    if len(acum_tr_acc)>1 and (len(acum_tr_acc)+1) % 1 == 0:
        if e>1:
            clear_output()
```

Comment: You cannot use softmax with one output neuron, you have 4 classes right? Then you should have 4 output neurons, and one-hot encode your labels (or use sparse categorical crossentropy)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I one-hot encoded my labels (5 classes) using to_categorical and changed the output layer to Dense(5, activation=softmax). But now the accuracy just remains 0. Any clue?

Comment: Its hard to say without all the details, is the loss decreasing? Can you update your question with your new code?

Comment: Sorry. Yes, the loss is decreasing. I did update  the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone gave me the solution. I just had to change this line:

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
             optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001),
             metrics=['Accuracy'])
```

For this:

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                 optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001),
                 metrics=['acc'])
```

I also changed the lines in the final loop relating to accuracy. The one-hot encoding was necessary as well.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is really bad practice.

You can either train for `n_epocas` using your current method and add callbacks to get the best weights (ex [ModelCheckpoint](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint)) or use [tf.GradientTape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape) but using `model.fit()` for one epoch at a time can lead to weird results, since your optimizer doesn't know which epoch it is at.

I suggest keeping your current code but training for `n_epocas` all in one go and report the results here (accuracy + loss).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I did it like you say (model.fit(epochs=20...)) but the accuracy still remained 0 all the time. The loss was fluctuating with a minimum of 0.65 in the validation set.